# how to save image to folder and save imagePaths to database in MEAN stack using Multer

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express, multer

I have a `image collection` of following schema:

```
{
"productId": {type: String},
"imagePaths": {type: Array}
}
```

I want to upload multiple images and store corresponding `image-paths` to database.
I searched, and came to know that `Multer` can perform this action, but I am unable to upload and save image-paths for multiple images.

---

I tried with this Angular code,

```
scope.demoMethod = function(){
    console.log('Method fired.');
    var product = $scope.product; 
    $http.post('/demo/upload', $scope.product)
      .then(function (res) { 
         console.log('Form Data ::' + $scope.product);
    });
 },
```

But I am getting error, cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

At first you need to define disk storage, the place where your file should be saved

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, `${global.uploadDir}/temp`); // folder path
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, `${uuid()}.${mime.extension(file.mimetype)}`); // file name here
  }
});

multer = multer({ storage });
```

Then add multer in your routes as middleware

```
router.post('/upload', multer.any(), (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.files) // should be array of files you have uploaded
    const imagePaths = [];
    req.files.forEach(f => {
      imagePaths.push(f.path);
    });
    const product = new Product(); // model name
    product.imagePaths = imagePaths;
    ...
    product.save();
    ...
});
```

Also you can specify files' filter

```
const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
    const isAllowed = utils.isAllowed(mime.extension(file.mimetype)); // your validation condition here
    if (!isAllowed) {
      return cb(new Error('This file is not allowed'));
    }
    cb(null, true);
}

multer = multer({ storage, fileFilter });
```

and limit

```
const limits = { fileSize: 50 * 1024 * 1024 /* 50MB */ };

multer = multer({ storage, limits });
```

Comment: I tried your code with this **Angular code**, 
`scope.demoMethod = function(){
  console.log('Method fired.');
 var product = $scope.product;
      $http.post('/demo/upload', $scope.product).then(function (res) {
        console.log('Form Data ::' + $scope.product);
      });
}`, 
But I am getting error, `cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined`